# Chrome extension: can detect drag&drop in address bar?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, drag-and-drop

I want to capture the dragging action for the address bar (and provide a space to drop the link to)

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

This already works, only you have to drag and drop the favicon, not the text. Would that be an acceptable solution? You can drop it into any form field.